# I'm getting "found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been running Ruby on Rails on my laptop for about a month now, but when I wanted to run the server in this instance (and it was working fine a few hours ago) I now receive this message.  How can I get the server to run again please?

```
C:\Sites\LaunchPage>rails s
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>):
    found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 17 column 17 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/figaro-0.6.3/lib/figaro.rb:21:in `raw'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/figaro-0.6.3/lib/figaro.rb:17:in `env'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/figaro-0.6.3/lib/figaro/railtie.rb:7:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:67:in `inherited'
    from C:/Sites/LaunchPage/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:LaunchPage>'
    from C:/Sites/LaunchPage/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Start by looking at psych.rb on line 203 as per the error message `/psych.rb:203:in parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token a t line 17 column 17 (Psych::SyntaxError)`

Comment: whats on `C:/Sites/LaunchPage/config/application.rb:13`?

Comment: Interesting, your folder is called `ruby 1.9.3`, but actually it is running on `1.9.1`. There could be some compatibility issues.

Comment: @dax line 203 says    `parser.parse yaml, filename`

Comment: @Magnuss 1.9.1 is the API version, 1.9.3 is the Ruby version.

Comment: @sevenseacat it says `class Application < Rails::Application`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This error is originating from the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro), which would indicate to me that you probably have a syntax error in `config/application.yml`. Double check this file for any incorrect YAML syntax.

Comment: Thank you - double checked and loaded default application.yml file so the server runs!

Comment: I am not using `Figaro gem` but still end up with this error. could u pls help?

Comment: I think the line sometimes is not the one indicated in the log. As Ryan suggests, check the WHOLE file

Comment: Another common character that can cause this parse errer is using unescaped % in values

Comment: My texteditor has a tendency to mix up tabs and spaces. I made sure that my application.yaml file didn't contain any tabs (replacing with spaces) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I was able to get my `application.yml` file fixed by removing any tabbed indentations when using Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 143):

YAML does not accept TAB characters (`\t`) for indentation. Look for those in your `config/application.yml` and replace with 2 spaces.

(*or there may be other syntax errors, as suggested by Ryan. But I'm betting on this one*)

Comment: For me it was exactly that. Judging by the upvotes, I am not the first.

Comment: Easy mistake to make!

Comment: tip: don't use tab for indentation while formatting YAML files

Answer (score 17):

May not be your specific example, but the title of the Stack Overflow resulted in me being on this post so for those working with this error, it may be due to:

en.yml or a translation yml or any yaml...

That doesn't have double quotes around a string interpolation

```
points:
  other: %{points} points
```

Correction:

```
points:
  other: "%{points} points"
```

Comment: Or if you keep yaml data in heredoc format without quotes around "values", it will also complain. Put values in quotes to avoid errors.

Comment: Note that this only matters if the string *starts* with interpolation

Answer (score 11):

I have the same issue with yours. I'm sure its the TAB characters (\t) issue. Please replace with 2 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You should check all important configuration files that contains YAML. I had the same error when tried to `rake db:seed`, and it turns out that I had TAB character in commented block in `config/database.yml`.

If you are not sure, use some online YAML parser, i.e. http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/.

Comment: yup. my tabs were in config/secrets.yml

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when one of yaml files get syntax error "*no tab in yaml*", yaml files maybe `database.yaml`, `application.yaml` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also happen when you use undeclared variables inside your yaml, which causes an indentation problem.
In my case it was something like:

```yaml
props:
    prop1: @app.prop1@
    prop2: @app.prop2@
```

So make sure all your variables are declared.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error occurred because of a faulty `credentials.yml.enc`.

According to the [Rails Active Storage documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html), when using Google Cloud Storage, one can use this configuration:

```
google:
  service: GCS
  credentials:
    type: "service_account"
    project_id: ""
    private_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:gcs, :private_key_id) %>
    private_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:gcs, :private_key).dump %>
    client_email: ""
    client_id: ""
    auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
    token_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
    client_x509_cert_url: ""
  project: ""
  bucket: ""
```

However, putting `private_key` within `credentials.yml.enc` is what caused the error. There is some character within the key that `psych` could not parse.

I ended up having to remove the private key from `credentials.yml.enc` and used this instead:

```
google:
  service: GCS
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/keyfile.json") %>
  project: ""
  bucket: ""
```

Weirdly, the configuration worked locally, but not on CentOS 8 Stream.

Answer (score -2):

[[image: Text editor screenshot]]

development:
DEV_DB_PASSWORD: 'qaz'
staging:
STAG_DB_PASSWORD: 'qaz'

there should not be any space in every next line