# Rails s causing psych error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I run `rails s` I get the following error message. I have tried replacing all spaces with tabs and vice versa, but am unable to come to a solution.

**The console output is here:**

```
SEEMAs-Mac-mini:colloquy_new seemashenoy$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 18 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/Desktop/arjun/colloquy_new/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/Desktop/arjun/colloquy_new/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/Desktop/arjun/colloquy_new/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/Desktop/arjun/colloquy_new/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/seemashenoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**And my database.yml file is below**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: colloquy_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356278/i-suddenly-receive-an-error-when-running-my-rails-server

Comment: I did. And it seems to be an issue of some tabs. I just cant find where. I think I'll just rewrite all the YAML files.