# Vagrant laravel Homestead error when running the vagrant up command on on windows 8.1

Tags: ruby

I am desperately in need of help please. After installing vagrant, virtual box, and initialising Homestead, when i run the vagrant up command it feeds back an error -- C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 25 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError).

i have checked other solutions to this that worked for some people, solutions likes replacing TAB with spaces, but all to know avail, please anyone HELP!!!..its been 4days already ... the complete error message is shown below..

C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in parse': (): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 25 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError) from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:inparse_stream'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:318:in parse' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:245:inload'
from C:/Users/Ekwonwa Henry/Homestead/Vagrantfile:25:in block in ' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:incall'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in load' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:inblock (2 levels) in load'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in each' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:inblock in load'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in each' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:inload'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in initialize' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:innew'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in vagrantfile' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:inhost'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in block in action_runner' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:incall'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in run' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:inhook'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in unload' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/bin/vagrant:177:inensure in

'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/bin/vagrant:177:in `'

MY Homestead.yaml file is shown below..

ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/web/sites
to: /home/vagrant/Code/sites

sites:
- map: test.app
to: /home/vagrant/sites/test

databases:
- homestead

I am using windows 8.1, and a first timer here..please help..

The psch.rb file is very large, but line 370 is where the yaml file was parsed == parser.parse yaml, filename.

while line 25 in the error messages turns out to be just a comment that says === # and emitting capabilities. In addition to wrapping libyaml, Psych also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I'm getting "found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356278/im-getting-found-character-that-cannot-start-any-token-while-scanning-for-the)

Have a look at this post, it could be that there is a syntax error your application.yml file. The link I have shared seems strikingly similar to your issue.

Comment: ...thanks for your help, just checked the link you pasted, but I can't seem to locate either the application.yaml or database.yaml file they all had edited...